# Using last-child to style last post in a loop

Tags: loops, css

I'm using border-bottom to add a line between posts in search results, but that leaves an extra line at the bottom of the page. I'm trying to use `last-child` in my style sheet to remove that extra line. Adding `last-child` removes all the lines in the loop though. Here's what I have:

```
.results {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #666; 
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.results:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Here's the HTML from my content-search.php:

```
<div class="results-container">
    <div class="results">
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <header class="entry-header">
                <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h1>' ); ?>
            </header><!-- .entry-header -->
                <span class="preview-artwork-info">Content...</span>
        </article><!-- #post-## -->
    </div><!-- .results -->
</div><!-- .results-container -->
```

Comment: `:last-child` pseudo-selector doesn't work with classes, only tags. Without seeing what your HTML looks like for a post any answer will be guess work.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I've added my HTML and clarified the question a little bit. Let me know if you have any suggestions of how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: You could try `.results-container > div:last-child` ( assuming `results-container` holds all your `results` ) but it may not be reliable. You may want to jump in the template files and add a counter to manually add a `first` and `last` class.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar challenge where I was adding `<hr>` tag between every post/notification for separating them.
I tried using "last-child" selector but it was removing all the separators.
So instead I used "forloop.last" method like this:

```
 {% for n in notifications %}
     {{n}}
     {% if forloop.last %}{% else %}<hr>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This works fine. Hope this helps!!