# How to style last-child: exerpt in wordpress loop?

Tags: wordpress, css, loops

[I've seen this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530080/using-last-child-to-style-last-post-in-a-loop) but it's not exactly relevant to what I'm trying to do. I have a simple blog loop in which each blog has an `<div class="exerpt">`for the preview of the blog text. All of my posts have a `border-bottom` and I'm simply trying to get rid of the `border-bottom`, as well as make other adjustments for the `last-child`. However every element is being styled, not just the last one. Please note I'm using the [mighty html5blank](http://html5blank.com)

index.php

```
<div class="page-section" style="padding-top:150px;">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <?php get_template_part('loop'); ?>

        <?php get_template_part('pagination'); ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

loop.php

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <h2 class="journal-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h2>
        <span class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> </span>
        <!-- post thumbnail -->
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); // Declare pixel size you need inside the array ?>
            </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- /post thumbnail -->

        <!-- post title -->

        <!-- /post title -->


        <div class="exerpt">
            <?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?>
        </div>


    </article>

.exerpt {
    margin-bottom:80px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #999;
    padding:40px 0px 80px 0px;
}
.exerpt:last-child {
    border:none;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `article:last-of-type .excerpt {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a separate class for the last item in the loop by doing something like this:

First add this before the loop starts:

```
<?php $post_counter = 0; ?>
```

Add this within the loop:

```
<?php $post_counter++; ?>
```

Then modify your excerpt code:

```
<div class="exerpt <?php if( $post_counter == count( $posts ) ) echo 'last-post'?>">
        <?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.last-post {
  border:none;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```